# Does DotNetOpenAuth 4.3 work with Entity Framework 6?

Tags: entity-framework, dotnetopenauth

I created an empty project in VS2013 and added these packages:

- DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet
- Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core
- Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDb
- Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth

In the process, Entity Framework 5 was added to the project. I manually installed EF6 and now I get this error when I try to authenticate a user with an external provider:

"Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'."

I checked the DNOA documentation but it does not say a word about dependencies/requisites.

Does anybody know if DotNetOpenAuth can work with EF6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth does not have EntityFramework as a dependency. The samples however do use EF. You must have some of your own code that uses entity framework.

That said, it sounds to me like you need to add a binding redirect or jiggle your entityframework configuration a bit in your web.config file.